# Access to base class from Property Attribute

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create attribute which will generate identity number key for each object in class range. So i need to know which class contain parameter connected with attribute. 
I create something like this:

```
class SampleModel
{
    [Identity(typeof(SampleModel))]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class IdentityAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly int _step;
    private readonly Type _objectType;

    public IdentityAttribute(Type type)
    {
        _step = 1;
        _objectType = type;
    }

    public object GenerateValue()
    {
        return IdentityGenerator.GetGenerator(_objectType).GetNextNum(_step);
    }
}
```

But i'm wondering is there any method which will allow me to get Type of base class (in this case SampleMethod) in IdentityAttribute constructor without sending it as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method -- an instance of `Attribute` does not know what it was decorating.

But the code that *creates* the instance does, so depending on usage you could inject this information externally:

```
 var identityAttribute = (IdentityAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(...);

 // If you can call GetCustomAttribute successfully then you can also easily
 // find which class defines the decorated property
 var baseClass = ... ;

 // And pass this information to GenerateValue
 var value = identityAttribute.GenerateValue(baseClass);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do it this way.